# How to render a page to pdf after a redirection?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

QUESTION

I am trying to get a pdf of a report from a website which needs login. So I am first logging in to the website which then redirects to the page I want access to. I need to hook the onLoadFinished function to the     page.render function. Here is the code I am using:

```
page.open(BASE_URL + Report_URL).then(function(status) {
        console.log(status);
        try{
            page.evaluate(function(){      
                setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById("username").value = "admin";
                document.getElementById("password").value = "admin";
                document.getElementById("submit").click();
                },100)                  
            })

        page.property('onLoadFinished', function(status,page) {
            console.log('==== onLoadFinished()');
            try{
                console.log('  status: ' + status );
                page.render("report.pdf")
            }catch(ex){
                var fullMessage = "\nJAVASCRIPT EXCEPTION";           
                console.log(fullMessage);
            }
        },page);
        }catch(ex){
            var fullMessage = "\nJAVASCRIPT EXCEPTION";

            console.log(fullMessage);
        }

    });
```

BUT,
Nothing happens, even exception does not come. 
How can this be achieved? I want to chain the onloadFinished function to another function which can render the page as pdf...pls help!!

#### Environment

- OS: Ubuntu 14
- Node version (`node -v`): v6.2.2
- package version: npm - 3.9.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using **this.render** instead of page.render.

Details here:- https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node/issues/675#issuecomment-312733078